# checking if a string contains a subString or part from subString in typeScript angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

i want to know the best way to check if a string contains a subString or part from subString in typeScript ?

for example i have a string path : "home/jobs/AddJobs"
And i want to check if it's equal or it contains : "home/jobs"

how can i do that in Angular 6 typescript ?

Comment: Is there a code that shows what you have tried by any chance ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a traditional and modern answer to this question:

```js
const path = 'home/jobs/AddJobs';

// Traditional
if (path.indexOf('home/jobs') > -1) {
    console.log('It contains the substring!');
}

// Modern
if (path.includes('home/jobs')) {
    console.log('It includes the substring!');
}
```

`string.prototype.includes` is available in ECMAScript 2015 and newer. If you target lower versions, `indexOf` works or you can use the [MDN Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Polyfill).

`includes` is functionally the same as `indexOf` but naturally returns a `boolean` value, so you don't need to write the `> -1` condition.